# Keep a field from updating in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm writing a Data Flow in which I make an upsert to a Cosmos DB NoSQL database. My goal is to use a field called `batch` to keep track of the date of insertion of a particular document, that is, I want this field to not change over an update. I see that the `AlterRow` action doesn't let me choose which fields to partially upsert or not. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: what is your source dataset or can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with HimanshuSinha-msft if you select `Upsert if` it will update all the columns Instead select `Update if` with condition

```json
equals(source1@id,source2@id)
```

[image]

And in sink setting select **Update method as `Allow update`** and pass partition key.

[image]

In mapping only select columns you want to update

> Mapping >> Uncheck Auto mapping >> select columns you want to update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use UPSERT , then it will update all the fields , but UPDATE should allow you to do so .

[image]